# Open a route in new tab/page and carry some state in react router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

I need to open a new page/tab with a given route on click of a mouse button and pass certain state. Is it possible without add that certain state to query parameter of new state?

Comment: I think it's not possible as in react when you open a new page/tab state will be reset. You should either add it to query parameter or use local storage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using window.open then you can access the parent via window.opener